# Google Kubernetes Engine's auto-pilot mode does not grant nodes Google Storage write access

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use the workflow orchestrator Snakemake with a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) [autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) cluster. My workflow needs to upload files to Google Cloud Storage buckets within the same project. Both [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v7.2.1/executing/cloud.html#setup-kubernetes-on-google-cloud-engine) and [GKE documentations](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs/kubernetes-container) specify that a Google Storage read-write scope should be specified when the cluster is created, via `--scopes storage-rw`.

I tried doing so with an autopilot cluster:

```
gcloud container --project "project-name" clusters create-auto "default-cluster" \
    --region "asia-southeast2" --release-channel "regular" \
    --network "projects/project-name/global/networks/default" \
    --subnetwork "projects/project-name/regions/asia-southeast2/subnetworks/default" \
    --cluster-ipv4-cidr "/17" --services-ipv4-cidr "/22" --scopes storage-rw
```

(I generated this command using the Google Cloud web console, then added the `--scopes storage-rw` argument at the end.)

But I still get a Snakemake error message related to lack of permission for Google Storage read-write:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/kubernetes-nccs-npc2/o/whoami.txt?fields=name&prettyPrint=false: Caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

It seems `--scopes storage-rw` does not work for the creation of autopilot clusters. Is this true? If so, how can I grant Google Storage read-write access to an autopilot cluster?

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error has more to do with the service account permissions running your cluster.  I'd make sure all the permissions are included, like *storage.ojjects.get*.  The error seems very permissions related.

```
Caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

You might be hitting this issue Google has reported:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes

I'd listen to their recommendations over mine.

When managing IAM roles, you can treat a service account either as a resource or as an identity. This [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/get-iam-policy) is to get the iam policy of a service account resource. There are other gcloud commands to manage IAM policies for other types of resources. For example, to manage IAM policies on a project, use the $ gcloud projects commands and for services use $ gcloud iam service-accounts.

This will return your service running the cluster w/ role assignment (it's the robot one :) )

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT-NAME>
```

The problem is sometimes running these commands requires special permissions too, so it becomes fools progress.  I think this link may be helpful.  it shows how to set permissions on a service-account.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/add-iam-policy-binding

Also here is Google dictionary of IAM permissions including
*storage.ojjects.get*.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles